# 56 bits DES got padded into 64 bits resulting in one byte decryption shortage

Tags: java, cryptography, des

I am having this question. I was given an encryption of DES with 56-bit key and input block size of 64 bit.

The block size is 8 bytes and I managed to decrypt the first 7th bytes. However, for the last bytes, DES is 56 bits and it got padded into 64 bits so my decrypted message is short of one byte.

And by the time I reached 7th loop, the plaintext1 is empty already and thus I am with one byte shortage.

Is there any way to solve this?

**Edit**

```
String plaintext1 = "ZZZZZZZ";
//removed line
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(plaintext1 .getBytes()));
System.out.println(plaintext1 );

public static byte[] paddingBytes(byte[] input, int blockSize) {
    int paddingSize = (blockSize - (input.length % blockSize)) % blockSize;
    byte[] padding = new byte[paddingSize];
    return concat(input, padding);
}
```

Comment: For more specific help please provide code and data.

Comment: @zaph Updated question. Sorry for being not able to post the code as this is my assignment and I am afraid of plagiarism so I can only describe on the concept

Comment: @zaph Any ideas?

Comment: Actually there are not 256 ASCII characters, there 128 and only about 96 are displayable. There are another 128 *extended* ASCII characters but there are still 32 that are not displayable. See [ASCII Code](http://www.ascii-code.com).

Comment: I got this plaintext1 with 7 bytes initialized to 'ZZZZZZZ' and I realized that I need to pad it so that it would become 8 bytes. So I did those in edited portion and I tried to print out the plaintext1, it gives me [65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 0] instead of 'ZZZZZZZ'. Is there any way for me to pad it such that it becomes 8 bytes but the value is still 'ZZZZZZZ'?

Comment: The correct padding length calculation is: `paddingSize = dataLength + blockSize - (dataLength % blockSize);` Data of block sizes that are an exact multiple of the block size need a full block of padding added, as does an input length of 0.

Answer (score 2):

DES has a 56-bit key encoded as 8-bytes, the least significant bit of each byte may be used for validating the parity of each byte, but it is not used by the cipher itself.

DES is a block oriented encryption method and as such the input data needs to be an exact multiple of the block size: 8-bytes. If the input data size is not an exact multiple it must be padded. If padding is needed it must be appended before encryption and removed after decryption. The usual padding is [PKCS#5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7). Usually a padding mode can be configured for a block cipher that uses the ECB or CBC mode of operation.

When the plainttext size cannot be calculated and the last byte can have any value then padding always needs to be applied. This is true even when the input size is an exact multiple of the block size. Otherwise it is impossible to tell if the last bytes consists of padding or plaintext after decryption.

Comment: Good answer but I found it somewhat imprecise so I changed the wording significantly. zaph, can you check if I messed anything up? You can of course roll back if you don't agree to the edits. Maybe it is a good idea to indicate that there is no direct link between key size and block size (otherwise I guess I just did with this comment :) )